# Is LDAP query against AD atomic?

Tags: ldap, atomic

I have a C++ application that runs LDAP queries against Active Directory.
The API I am using is explained at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-idirectorysearch-executesearch.

Is LDAP select query against active directory atomic?

Or to put it another way: What would happen if AD changes while a LDAP query is running?

EXample: Imagine there are two users and my query is collecting users list. After collecting user_1, another query deletes user_1 and creates user_3. Does my query collects user_2 and user_3 or the server hides the new changes from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, LDAP update operations are atomic (they target a single entry), but searches are not run within a transaction and will return entries as they are at the time the process reads them.